# filtering list by multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, filter

there is a list of users

```
filterData = [
  {
    "position":"lawyer", 
    "department_positions":[],
    "group_positions":[
      {"group":{"id":2,"code":"234","name":"group1"},"lead":false},
      {"group":{"id":1,"code":"123","name":"group12"},"lead":true}
    ]
  },
  {
    "position":"director", 
    "department_positions":[
      {"department":{"id":3,"code":"333","name":"subDep"},"lead":false}
    ],
    "group_positions":[
      {"group":{"id":2,"code":"234","name":"group1"},"lead":false},
      {"group":{"id":1,"code":"123","name":"group12"},"lead":true}
    ]
  },
  {
    "position":"director",
    "department_positions":[],
    "group_positions":[]
  }
]
```

and list of filters

```
categories = {
  "position":["lawyer","director"],
  "group_positions":["group1","group12"],
  "department_positions":["generalDep", "subDep"]
}
```

It is necessary to filter users taking into account the fact that several filters can be selected at the same time. For example, i want to find user with position = "director" and AND  group_positions = "group1" AND department_positions = "subDep"

my code doesn't allow filtering by multiple conditions. how can i fix it?

```
this.filter = this.filterData.filter(item => {
  for (let key in this.categories) {
    if (item[key].find(el => 
      this.categories[key].includes(
        el.group?.name || el.department?.name
      )
    )) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
})}
```

Comment: what's the expected output that you want there? filter function returns the whole index data if true otherwise doesn't return it if it's false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to employ an es6 class to give behavior to the object being filtered. Augment each object to determine if it matches the "category" object.

(from the example data, this assumes the OP is looking for a "product of sums" match: for *all* of the category keys match *at least one of* the category values)

```js
class FilterMe {
  constructor(item) {
    Object.assign(this, item);
  }
  namesForKey(key) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'position':
        return [this.position]; // always answer an array
      case 'group_positions':
        return this.group_positions.map(gp => gp.group.name);
      case 'department_positions':
        return this.department_positions.map(dp => dp.department.name);
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }
  // return true if a single filter key-value pair is matched
  matchesFilterKeyValue(filterKey, filterOptions) {
    const myNames = this.namesForKey(filterKey);
    const matches = filterOptions.filter(e => myNames.includes(e));
    return matches.length > 0;
  }
  // return true if all filter key-values pairs are matched
  matchesFilter(filter) {
    return Object.entries(filter).every(keyValue => {
      return this.matchesFilterKeyValue(...keyValue);
    })
  }
}

const filterData = [{
    "position": "lawyer",
    "department_positions": [],
    "group_positions": [{
      "group": {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "234",
        "name": "group1"
      },
      "lead": false
    }, {
      "group": {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "123",
        "name": "group12"
      },
      "lead": true
    }]
  },
  {
    "position": "director",
    "department_positions": [{
      "department": {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "333",
        "name": "subDep"
      },
      "lead": false
    }],
    "group_positions": [{
      "group": {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "234",
        "name": "group1"
      },
      "lead": false
    }, {
      "group": {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "123",
        "name": "group12"
      },
      "lead": true
    }]
  },
  {
    "position": "director",
    "department_positions": [],
    "group_positions": []
  }
]

const categories = {
  "position": ["lawyer", "director"],
  "group_positions": ["group1", "group12"],
  "department_positions": ["generalDep", "subDep"]
}


// convert the filterData to the objects and test them...
let objects = filterData.map(d => new FilterMe(d));
let matches = objects.filter(o => o.matchesFilter(categories))
console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
let filtered = example.filter(item => {
  let valid = false

  if (item.includes('something')) {
    valid = true
  }

  if (!valid) {
    // check second condition
  }

  return valid
})
```

Use a temporary placeholder so you don't immediately have to return true/false.